# How this code runs without overloading for the assignment operator

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constructor

I wonder how this code run specifically line 54 (line2 = line1) although there is no overloading for the assignment operator ?
It seems from the output that neither the copy constructor nor the normal constructor were called and surprisingly it gets output as expected 199 199

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line
{
   public:
      int getLength();
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor
      ~Line();                     // destructor

   private:
      int *ptr;
};

Line::Line(int len)
{
    cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
    ptr = new int;
   *ptr = *obj.ptr;
}

Line::~Line(void)
{
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    delete ptr;
}
int Line::getLength()
{
    return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj)
{
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main()
{
   Line line1(199);

   Line line2(1);
   line2 = line1; // How this is executed ??!
   cout << line1.getLength() << " " << line2.getLength() << endl ;
   /*display(line1);
   display(line2);*/

   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a copy assignment operator (`operator=`) for C++ classes. Since you haven't specified an implementation, the compiler has supplied a default version and that's what's getting called.

Comment: The default member wise copy will have both ptr pointing to the same memory and lead to a double delete and undefined behavior as a result.

Comment: [link to cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is undefined behavior.  You assign `line2 = line1` but have no user-defined assignment operator, so you use the default one provided by the compiler.  And the default one simply copies all the fields, which in your case includes an `int*`.  That gives you two copies of the same `int*`, leaks the value that `line2` previously pointed to, and eventually double-`delete`s the one `line1` originally pointed to.  The second `delete` of the same pointer, which occurs when `line1` goes out of scope at the end of `main()`, invokes undefined behavior.

If you have a destructor which frees resources, you probably need an assignment operator too.  See the Rule of Three: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

But the best solution is to stop using raw pointers.  Use a smart pointer and this problem will not occur in the first place, and you can omit your destructor.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That's right, I've clarified this in my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In a situation like this, writing your own copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor should be your last resort, not your first reaction.

Your first reaction should *usually* be to use some pre-defined class that already handles these chores for you. In this case, changing from a raw pointer to a `shared_ptr` (for only one possibility) cleans up the code fairly quickly. Using it, the code ends up something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Line
{
   public:
      int getLength();
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      ~Line();                     // destructor

      // copy constructor removed, because the one supplied by the 
      // compiler will be fine. Likewise the compiler-generated assignment
      // operator.
   private:
      shared_ptr<int> ptr;
};

Line::Line(int len)
{
    cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;

    // Note the use of make_shared instead of a raw `new`
    ptr = make_shared<int>(len);
}

Line::~Line(void)
{
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    // don't need to actually do anything--freeing is automatic
}
int Line::getLength()
{
    return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj)
{
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main()
{
   Line line1(199);

   Line line2(1);
   line2 = line1; // uses compiler-generated assignment operator (which works)
   cout << line1.getLength() << " " << line2.getLength() << endl ;
   display(line1);
   display(line2);

   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

Depending upon the situation, a `unique_ptr` might be a better fit than a `shared_ptr`. In this case, `shared_ptr` is probably easier to incorporate into the existing code though.

You might also want to read R. Martinho Fernandes' [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) blog post on this subject.

Comment: Does shared pointers work for c++11 only or it can work for the default one too ??

Comment: @Mis94: C++11 includes `std::shared_ptr`. An older compiler might include the same in an implementation of TR1. If you have an even older compiler than that, you might consider Boost's `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

If no user-defined copy assignment operators are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare one as an inline public member of the class.

This implicitly-declared copy assignment operator has the form `T& T::operator=(const T&)` if all of the following is true:

1. Each direct base B of T has a copy assignment operator whose parameters are B or `const B&` or `const volatile B&`
2. Each non-static data member M of T of class type or array of class type has a copy assignment operator whose parameters are `M` or `const M&` or `const volatile M&`

Otherwise the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator is declared as `T& T::operator=(T&)`. (Note that due to these rules, the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator cannot bind to a volatile lvalue argument)

Copied from [this article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) from CPPReference.